# Convert this sql statement to ORM or Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel

```
select distinct id from  (SELECT 
   distinct books.id,name
FROM
    authors,books,store.favorites,writers,users
        where 
     authors.writer_id = writers.id and

     books.id = authors.product_id and
     users.id=favorites.user_id and 
    books.id=favorites.product_id

order by  name asc) as newval
```

can someone please convert this sql statment to Eloquent ORM or Query Builder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is look like

```
DB::table('authors')->distinct()->select('books.id')
     ->join('books', 'books.id', '=', 'authors.product_id')
     ->join('store.favorites', 'books.id', '=', 'favorites.product_id')
     ->join('writers', 'authors.writer_id', '=', 'writers.id')
     ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'favorites.user_id')
 ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
```

P.s. Laravel gives good documentation about [Eloquent ORM](http://laravel.com/docs/queries)